# Ryzen 2400G amdgpu kernel crashes/warnings

Tags: drivers, amdgpu

I have an 18.04LTS system running on an Asus Prime B350 Plus. The AMDGPU driver generates lots of warnings and random system lockups.

I've installed the latest motherboard firmware updates, as well as the most recent Ubuntu updates.

But I get a lot of these:

> [479194.437897] [drm:generic_reg_wait [amdgpu]] *ERROR* REG_WAIT timeout 1us * 100 tries - tgn10_lock line:566

I suspect there's a memory leak associated with it, because eventually I get a general protection fault in

> kmem_cache_alloc (called from amdgpu_sync_fence) which is where I think the system locks up.

What do I need to do to get this integrated graphics working?

Comment: I'm still seeing this on a fairly regular basis. I'm surprised at how unstable this driver is after this much time.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.